# Calculate the average score for subgroups

Tags: r

In a data frame as input:

```
data.frame(group = c(1,1,1,2,2,3), number = c(10,10,10,5,5,1))
```

How is it possible to check which is the group number using the group column and calculate for every number the average score of the number column?

Example of expected output:

```
group avg_number

1     10
2      5
3      1
```

Comment: You can use `aggregate` `aggregate(number ~ group, df1, FUN = mean)`

Comment: `aggregate` works well.  If you don't like using formulas, you can use a grouped `tibble`. Load the `dplyr` package, then, assuming your data.frame is named `df` use: `df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarize(avg_number = mean(number))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group_by` from `dplyr`

```py
data <- data.frame(group = c(1,1,1,2,2,3), number = c(10,10,10,5,5,1))
data %>% 
       group_by(group) %>%
         summarise(avg= mean(number), .groups='drop')
```

Note that the `.groups="drop"` is just to avoid a message printing, but in this case you can omit it if you prefer.